# MySQL select multiple tables with one query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two MySQL tables:

- tbl_product: product_id, product_name, update_time, sale
- tbl_child_product: child_id, child_name, child_price, product_id

How to select all product with `sale`='1', order by `update_time`, the lowest price per product (store in `child_price` in tbl_child_product table) with one query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use inner join of both the tables as:

```
Select p.product_id, p.product_name, min(c.child_price), p.update_time
from tbl_product p inner join tbl_child_product c
on p.product_id = c.product_id
group by p.product_id
having sale='1'
order by p.update_time
```

Updated the answer as per question: Use `having sale='1'` to filter the results of `group by`

Answer (score 2):

May be UNION clause will help you.

(SELECT * from tbl_product where `product_id` = 'NULL')
UNION
(SELECT * from tbl_child_product where `child_id` = 'NUll')

and so on for all values .

Answer (score 1):

You could `join` between `tbl_product` and an aggregate query on `tbl_child_product`:

```
SELECT   p.product_id, p.product_name, c.lowest_price
FROM     tbl_product p
JOIN     (SELECT   product_id, MIN(child_price) lowest_price
          FROM     tbl_child_product
          GROUP BY product_id) c ON p.product_id = c.product_id
ORDER BY p.update_time
```

Comment: Hello, i use your query but it show up one product only, insteads of showing all product (order by update_time) with lowest price per product. Please help!

Comment: @hatxi This query should work, but maybe I misunderstood the requirement. Please edit your question with some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I updated the question: list all products that match the condition (sale=1) and include the min price of each product. The product list will order by update_time. Thanks!